# how to get quote id before placing order M2

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I am struggling to find which event I should use to get the quote id?
I want to save some data in db, want to save customer session id and quote id before placing an order?

Can someone suggest which I should use?

Comment: https://mage2-blog.com/magento-2-get-current-quote/ This will help you.

Comment: From customer session, what you want?

Answer (score 2):

> This will return current cart details.

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
    ...
) {
    $this->cart = $cart;
}

public function getCartDetails()
{
    $cart= $this->cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
}
```

you can make an observer for the same on event `checkout_cart_save_before`

> your event.xml will be

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_save_before">
        <observer name="checkout_cart_before" instance="Namespace\Modulename\Observer\GetQuoteId" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Answer (score 2):

- You can use **sales_model_service_quote_submit_success** event
- you **`can save a value`** in the order table also.

  ```
  public function __construct(
  \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutsession,
  \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $orderFacory
  ){
  $this->orderFacory = $orderFacory;
  $this->_checkoutsession = $checkoutsession;
  }
  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {
  $quote = $observer->getQuote();
  $order = $observer->getOrder();

  /* get quote id and order id */
  $quoteId = $observer->getQuote()->getQuoteId();
  $orderId = $observer->getOrder()->getOrderId();

  /* you can set something in order table */
  $order->setData('field', $array);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Use event `sales_order_place_before` to get quote id before save order

And your observer code would be like this:

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
   $QuoteID=$observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getQuoteId();
}
```